# Combining list of numbers and strings in python

Tags: python, r, list

As an `R` user, I know very little about python. I am using `python moviepy` to pick up a long list of photos to generate a video in `RStudio notebook`. What I did previously was to use `R` to generate the list of photos.

R code:

```
v_list <- c(paste0("v_", c(1:10, rep(10, 5), rep(11, 10)), ".jpg"))
```

and then in `python` chunk to convert this list to python, `v_list = r.v_list`.

I wonder if there is an easy way to generate the list directly in python. It appears there are many questions on this topic. Through those answers, I managed to produce the following code:

Python:

```
v_list = ["v_" + str(x) + ".jpg" for x in range(1, 10)]+["v_" + str(x) + ".jpg" for x in [10]*5] + ["v_" + str(x) + ".jpg" for x in [11]*10]
```

My question: is it possible to make this code simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```py
v_list = [f"v_{x}.jpg" for x in list(range(1, 10)) + [10] * 5 + [11] * 10]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just wonder what f in `f"v_{x}.jpg" means.

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang check out [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification)

Comment: Thanks, it may take a while for me to understand but it works for me!